# Trouble installing ggvegan in RStudio Version 1.1.463

Tags: r, installation

I am having issues installing ggvegan from GitHub using

```
devtools::install_github("gavinsimpson/ggvegan")
```

in R. When I run this code, it comes up with an error message, despite installing other packages. I am not sure if this is compatible with the latest version of R? Please can someone advise on how to get around this? Thanks.

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("gavinsimpson/ggvegan")
```

> Error: Failed to install 'ggvegan' from GitHub:
>       (converted from warning) packages ‘vegan’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘tidyr’, ‘permute’, ‘tibble’, ‘dplyr’, ‘purrr’, ‘stringr’ are in use and will not be installed